# Android: Passing context to helper class results in NPE

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I am creating an Android app and I am trying to use a `SettingsManager` class to read and write preferences. To use this, I have to pass context to this `SettingsManager` in order to use the `SharedPreferences` API. However, my code keeps giving me a `NullPointerException`. Can anyone tell me why?

Main.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        setButton();
    }
```

...

```
public void setButton(){
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SettingsManager settings = SettingsManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
            settings.getUserName();
        }
    });
}
```

SettingsManager.java

```
static Context context;

private SettingsManager(){
    sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(settingsfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static SettingsManager getInstance(Context cntxt){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new SettingsManager();
    }
    context = cntxt;
    return instance;
}
```

The NPE happens on this line:

```
sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(settingsfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: post your logcat output please.

Comment: Please do not hold onto random `Context` objects in static data members -- you are leaking memory in this case. `SettingsManager` is largely pointless (`SharedPreferences` are already cached by the framework), but if you insist on keeping it, hold onto `getApplicationContext()` in the static data member, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not *resulting* in a `NPE`. What you are doing wrong is accessing   `context` before assigning it. Change your code like

```
private SettingsManager(Context context){
   context = cntxt;
   sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(settingsfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}


public static SettingsManager getInstance(Context cntxt){
    if(instance == null){        
        instance = new SettingsManager(cntxt);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Oh god, appearently I am not awake yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the context from the view object.

```
SettingsManager settings = SettingsManager.getInstance(v.getContext());
```